# How to setup my click callback function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a callback function on click (when user clicks the button second time).

I have

```
$('#toggle').live('click', function(){
        $this=$(this);
        $this.attr('id', 'detail')
        turn()
    }, function(){
        $this.attr('id','detail_close')
        turn()
    })
```

I can't seem to change the id to detail_close and call turn() again after the second click. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var count = 0; // a counter
   $(document).on('click', '#toggle', function(){

        $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('id', 'detail');  // may use prop(), instead of attr()

        count++;  // increase counter value

        // checking for counter value
        if(count > 1) {
             // do something on second click

             $this.prop('id', 'detail_close'); // change id
             turn();  // call turn()

             count = 0; // reset the counter
        }
    });
```

As `.live()` is deprecated, so in order to make delegate event handling use `.on()` method like:

```
$(StaticParent).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction)
```

Comment: I can't use on becasue I am using Jquery 1.64

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#toggle', function(){
    $this=$(this);
    if($this.prop('id') == 'detail'){
        $this.prop('id', 'detail_close');
        turn();
    }else{
        $this.prop('id', 'detail');
        turn();
    }
});
```

We use .on and .prop in the newest version of jQuery.